# Exporting a complex item to Unreal 4

Tags: objects, export, unreal-engine

I've been playing around with Blender the last few days and decided to try and export an object into UE4.

I made a fairly complicated, and definitely non symmetrical, rock to try it out on. I want to see how the details translate into UE4. I textured it with nodes too.

I haven't got a UV map for it, because I have no idea where to start with an object like this.

How do I go about doing this? If there are readily available tutorials I haven't managed to stumble into, I'd grateful.

I've attached a picture of the rock for clarity.
[image: Rocky McRock Face]

Incidentally, I don't mind starting over from scratch if I've done something I shouldn't have. I'd take me 20 minutes to knock together another.1

Comment: I am not sure I entirely understand your question. Are you asking about importing into Unreal or about texturing, or about materials?  If your plan is to export into game engines (whichever they are) my advice to you is to not waste too much time with materials in Blender beyond basic UV Unwrapping, materials are mostly not exportable, you should create them in the engine editor in question. Especially not Cycles materials or materials using builtin procedural textures beyond. See one of these https://www.google.com/search?q=Blender+beginner+unwrap&tbm=vid

Comment: For starters, this model seems to have way too much verts/faces for a basic model - as long as this model isn't intended to be the only model in your scene (correct me if I'm wrong). If you want to create game assets the usual way is "Create hi-poly model - use it to retopologize a low-poly model - uv-unwrap that low-poly model - bake textures for diffuse/normal/specularity/displacement... - export lo-poly model to fbx - import lo-poly model to unity - re-create material, if necessary - done". Also watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHmw783xreY for a good hi-poly to lo-poly rock tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

What Duarte said. Safer to deal with this material directly on the UE editor.

But either way here are some images that might help you think about the UV maps for this rock:

https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/plant-tree/other/realistic-rock

Answer (score 0):

Typically sculpting is used to create high-poly or high-detail meshes. And typically these are not used in your game engine. High poly models are used to bake the detailed information they have into textures and those textures are applied to low poly meshes that have an identical shape but do not have all the fine detail. Because they're lower in detail (less polygons) they are better for performance and also easier to unwrap.

So instead of importing this rock into UE4, create a low poly version of this rock that has the same overall shape, size and position, but way less polygons and unwrap it. You then need a process called baking, or texture baking. Blender has some tools for this, but you could also use something like xNormal.
They all work in the same way, they take a high poly model and a similar low poly model and project the detail from the high poly onto a texture that fits on the low poly. Also, look into 'normal maps' and how to bake them. These texture maps are one of the most important ones to create an impression of high detail without costing too much preformance.